# Click and drag box over image - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I'm having trouble getting the `selectionBox` not to center. In the image below, I tried to draw a box around the word **Final Bill** (accented ms paint box) by clicking and dragging but the resulting `selectionBox` (dashed line in red) that outputs always starts in the center. The rectangle values that are calculated and saved in the mouseUp event are all correct, suggesting perhaps a XAML display issue?

I am very knew to WPF/XAML and front end stuff in general.

**EDIT:** By placing just the `selectionBox` in a `<Canvas>` tag I was able to get it almost working. It no longer centers but the start point appears to be twice as far from the left and top borders as the mouse is when clicked.

[image: XAML output]

XAML

```
<DockPanel Width="Auto" Margin="225,65,5,5">
    <Border x:Name="img_Border" ClipToBounds="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Image x:Name="img_Box" ClipToBounds="True" MouseMove="img_Box_MouseMove" MouseWheel="img_Box_MouseWheel">
                </Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Rectangle x:Name="selectionBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeDashArray="3,1">
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

I can get the `selectionBox` to work correctly if I use `<Canvas>` tags. but that causes the image to not fit inside the `<DockPanel>`.

c#

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    img_Box.MouseLeftButtonDown += img_Box_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    img_Box.MouseLeftButtonUp += img_Box_MouseLeftButtonUp;
    img_Box.MouseMove += img_Box_MouseMove;

    Point mouseDownPos;
}

private void img_Box_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    img_Box.CaptureMouse();
    var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)img_Box.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);

    double BoxX = (e.GetPosition(img_Box).X / img_Box.ActualWidth) * 1;
    double BoxY = (e.GetPosition(img_Box).Y / img_Box.ActualHeight) * 1;
    double xValue = Math.Round((BoxX * img_Box.Source.Width), 0);
    double yValue = Math.Round((BoxY * img_Box.Source.Height), 0);

    StartDrag = new System.Windows.Point(xValue, yValue);
    mouseDownPos.X = (int)xValue;
    mouseDownPos.Y = (int)yValue;

    Canvas.SetLeft(selectionBox, xValue);
    Canvas.SetTop(selectionBox, yValue);
    selectionBox.Width = 0;
    selectionBox.Height = 0;
    selectionBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void img_Box_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double x = e.GetPosition(img_Box).X;
    double y = e.GetPosition(img_Box).Y;
    double BoxX = (x / img_Box.ActualWidth) * 1;
    double BoxY = (y / img_Box.ActualHeight) * 1;
    double xValue = Math.Round((BoxX * img_Box.Source.Width), 0);
    double yValue = Math.Round((BoxY * img_Box.Source.Height), 0);

    if (mouseDownPos.X < xValue)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(selectionBox, mouseDownPos.X);
        selectionBox.Width = xValue - mouseDownPos.X;
    }
    else
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(selectionBox, xValue);
        selectionBox.Width = mouseDownPos.X - xValue;
    }
    if (mouseDownPos.Y < yValue)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(selectionBox, mouseDownPos.Y);
        selectionBox.Height = yValue - mouseDownPos.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(selectionBox, yValue);
        selectionBox.Height = mouseDownPos.Y - yValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just two cents, I hope that's mock data in the example and you're not sharing client account information on the internet... :x

Comment: Since you are not using a `<Canvas>` element, you cannot use `Canvas.SetLeft()` or `Canvas.SetTop()`.
What you could try is setting the `Margin` property of the `Rectangle` (e.g. `Margin="10,30,0,0"` would mean "distance from left = 10, distance from top = 30"); this requires that you also set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` and `VerticalAlignment="Top"` on the `Rectangle`. This is just an idea; I did not test it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The account was recently dispositioned but I changed the image anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish here but if you just need a border around that text and not to allow the user to move it around with the mouse, set the image to be the background of the Grid and then partition the Grid so that one of the grid cells is directly above that text you want to place the border around. Place the border within that cell and If all the bill images are exactly the same size and have the text in exactly the same location it will always be directly over that text as long as you do not allow users to resize the image... If you want the scrolling just put the entire grid within the `ScrollViewer` control.

Something like this:

```
  <Grid>  
  <Grid.Background>
    <VisualBrush TileMode="None" >
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/> //Distance from the left edge of the image to the right edge of the border around the "Final Bill" text.
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="150"/> //Distance from the top of the image to the top of the desired location of the border around the "Final Bill" text.
      <RowDefinition Height="50"/> //Desired height of the border around the "Final Bill" text.
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1"/>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, Allow me to clarify. I have an image that the user is allowed to zoom and scroll. upon clicking down and dragging, I want to simply draw the red box. much like clicking and dragging behaves on a windows desktop.